# How to close a OTRS ticket using pyotrs in python?

Tags: python, otrs, ticket-system

I am new to ticketing system - OTRS. I can successfully create a OTRS ticket using pyotrs, also access ticket attributes like ticket number etc. However, I dont have any idea how to close a ticket using otrs ticket-id or ticket number. On close inspection in OTRS documentation I got the following -
`"Attention: PyOTRS can only retrieve Ticket data at the moment!".`

So any suggestion as to how to close an OTRS ticket with or without python (non-GUI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have a webservice named "GenericTicketConnectorREST" (because of the pyotrs example webservice). In there you need to have an operation called TicketUpdate (last entry in the image).
[image]

Under "Configuration" you should add/change the entry for TicketUpdate (i had to change it):

[image]

Using Postman (or any tool to send your rest request) you can send the following JSON to close a Ticket. Remember to set the Postman request to `Patch`, as it is set in the configuration.

```
{
   "UserLogin":"root@localhost",
   "Password":"root",
   "TicketID":"1",
   "Ticket":{
      "State": "closed successful"
   },
   "Article":{
      "ContentType":"text/plain; charset=utf8",
      "Subject":"Ticket closed",
      "Body":"Ticket closed"
   }
}
```

The URL Depends on the name of your webservice and how you set the routing (TicketUpdate). `http://localhost/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/TicketUpdate`.
You can change anything listed in the api for the operation "TicketUpdate". Eveything under the key `Data` is something you can add to change.
https://doc.znuny.org/doc/api/otrs/6.0/Perl/Kernel/GenericInterface/Operation/Ticket/TicketUpdate.pm.html